# Javascript Split String in Array to Objects in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object, split

I have this Array `["2.900000F02A_1313_01","2.600000F02A_1315_03","2.900000F02A_1354_01"]`

And I want to split it like this:

```
[
    {"name":"F02A_1313_01", "Voltage":"2.900000"}, 
    {"name":"F02A_1315_03", "Voltage":"2.600000"},
    {"name":"F02A_1354_01", "Voltage":"2.900000"}
]
```

This is my Code that doesn't work:

```
for (var i in msg.strg) {
     array.push(i.split(/[a-zA-Z].*/g));
 }
```

Does somebody know how I can do this?

Comment: What is the general rule to know where to split?  First non-numeric character?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could split with a group.

```js
const
    data = ["2.900000F02A_1313_01", "2.600000F02A_1315_03", "2.900000F02A_1354_01"],
    result = data.map(string => {
        const [Voltage, name] = string.split(/([a-z].*$)/i);
        return { name, Voltage };
    });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also make the match a bit more specific, matching the digits for Voltage `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` in group 1 , and a case insensitive char a-z followed by word characters `(F\w+)` in group 2.

```js
const arr = ["2.900000F02A_1313_01","2.600000F02A_1315_03","2.900000F02A_1354_01"];
const result = arr.map(s => {
    const m = s.match(/^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)([a-z]\w+)$/i);
    return {name: m[2], Voltage: m[1]}
});
console.log(result);
```